# Not able to run on android 9+ devices

Tags: java, android, android-storage

Manifest:-     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
String[] items;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
    runtimePermission();
}

public void runtimePermission(){

    Dexter.withContext(this).withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                    displaySongs();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                    permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            }).check();
}

public ArrayList<File> findSongs(File file){

    ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    File[] files = file.listFiles();

    for (File singlefile : files){
        if (singlefile.isDirectory() && !singlefile.isHidden()) {
            arrayList.addAll(findSongs(singlefile));
        } else {
            if (singlefile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || singlefile.getName().endsWith(".wav")){
                arrayList.add(singlefile);
            }
        }
    }
    return arrayList;
}

public void displaySongs(){
    final ArrayList<File> mysongs = findSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    items = new String[mysongs.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < mysongs.size(); i++) {
        items[i] = mysongs.get(i).getName().replace(".mp3", "").replace(".wav", "");
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items );
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
    android:padding="8dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat :-

2022-02-08 14:56:52.834 9348-9348/com.example.mymusic E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mymusic, PID: 9348
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=42, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.mymusic/com.karumi.dexter.DexterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4977)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5018)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2073)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7563)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:994)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
at com.example.mymusic.MainActivity.displaySongs(MainActivity.java:79)
at com.example.mymusic.MainActivity$1.onPermissionGranted(MainActivity.java:39)
at com.karumi.dexter.MultiplePermissionsListenerToPermissionListenerAdapter.onPermissionsChecked(Unknown Source:35)
at com.karumi.dexter.MultiplePermissionListenerThreadDecorator$1.run(Unknown Source:8)
at com.karumi.dexter.MainThread.execute(Unknown Source:6)
at com.karumi.dexter.MultiplePermissionListenerThreadDecorator.onPermissionsChecked(Unknown Source:7)
at com.karumi.dexter.DexterInstance.onPermissionsChecked(Unknown Source:56)
at com.karumi.dexter.DexterInstance.updatePermissionsAsGranted(Unknown Source:26)
at com.karumi.dexter.DexterInstance.onPermissionRequestGranted(Unknown Source:0)
at com.karumi.dexter.Dexter.onPermissionsRequested(Unknown Source:4)
at com.karumi.dexter.DexterActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(Unknown Source:51)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:8408)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8253)

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio`. That tag is for problems/questions related to the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question.

Comment: The variable `listView` in `MainActivity` is never initialized. The call `listView.setAdapter(adapter);` results in a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `listView` in `MainActivity` is never initialized. The call `listView.setAdapter(adapter);` results in a `NullPointerException`.

In `onCreate()` you need to do something like this (after calling `setContentView()`:

```
listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

Comment: logcat :- E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
     
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array                                        The problem is with storage permissions in android 10+ otherswise the same code works normally on below android 9 devices.

Comment: Did you review this? https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes

Comment: First of all thank you and Yes I read that but I don't know how to implement this. I want to access music files stored in the device please guide or share some references.